# Using subquery to gather the boss' name SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I am supposed to list the names of the employees and their bosses...

The problem is that I have to use the same table... I don't think I have to use a JOIN, or do I?

```
SELECT
first_name AS NOMBRE,
manager_id AS ID_JEFE,

(SELECT first_name FROM employees WHERE employee_id = ID_JEFE) AS JEFE

FROM employees

ORDER BY NOMBRE ASC;
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: How can you tell it doesn't work?

Answer (score 3):

it does not work because on subquery level there's no ID_JEFE column.

A correct query could be:

```
SELECT
    a.first_name AS NOMBRE,
    a.manager_id AS ID_JEFE,
    b.first_name AS JEFE
FROM employees a left join employees b ON b.employee_id=a.manager_id

ORDER BY a.first_name ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT first_name AS NOMBRE, manager_id AS ID_JEFE,
(SELECT first_name FROM employees WHERE employee_id = manager_id ) AS JEFE
FROM employees
ORDER BY NOMBRE ASC;
```